# Using the Google Web Speech API on mobile

Tags: javascript, html

I'm currently working with the Google Web Speech API in my project. Everything is working fine on desktop, but whenever I try to use my webapp or Googles API Demo on mobile with Chrome, the recocnized words appear several times:

> This is a test
>   Thisthisthis isis a testtesttesttest

Is there any fix for that or are there any easy to use alternatives?

Comment: What code you have written?

Comment: I took the code fron the WebSpeech API Demonstration

Comment: https://github.com/GoogleChrome/webplatform-samples/tree/master/webspeechdemo

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had the same issue and searched the net but found no sollution. So I checked the code and this repeating the final results issue is caused by

```
final_transcript += event.results[i][0].transcript;
```

Just eliminate the '+'.

```
    recognition.onresult = function(event) {
      var interim_transcript = '';
      if (typeof(event.results) == 'undefined') {
        recognition.onend = null;
        recognition.stop();
        upgrade();
        return;
      }
      for (var i = event.resultIndex; i < event.results.length; ++i) {
        if (event.results[i].isFinal) {
          final_transcript = event.results[i][0].transcript;
        } else {
          interim_transcript += event.results[i][0].transcript;
        }
      }
      final_transcript = capitalize(final_transcript);
      final_span.innerHTML = linebreak(final_transcript);
      interim_span.innerHTML = linebreak(interim_transcript);
      if (final_transcript || interim_transcript) {
        showButtons('inline-block');
      }
   };
```

Maybe it's the same hack on the the interim results. I won't need them so I didn't checked that.