# Chrome web speech recognition api results returning repeated words?

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome, speech-recognition, google-speech-api

I am trying the web speech recognition api for speech to text. There is an online demo here  https://www.google.com/intl/en/chrome/demos/speech.html

but if I try that or even implement it myself, there is a problem of it repeating words. So if I say `test` it comes back as `testtest`. Ive seen at least two other people comment on the same issue on other forums. Is this a known issue/bug?

Thanks

Comment: A google search brought me to this question - did you manage to figure the root cause for this issue?

Comment: unfortunately I did not. Seems kind of weird no one is talking about this much.

Comment: Looks like this worked for somebody: https://stackoverflow.com/a/38247791/131050

Answer (score 0):

in php split the string to words and pass each word to this function and get back unique word.

```
 function remove_duplicate_char($str) 
{
    $l = strlen($str);
    //echo "<br>==".$l;
    //first characters
    $firstchar = $str[0].$str[1].$str[2];
    //echo "<br>===".$firstchar;
    //repeatstart
    $repeat = strpos($str,$firstchar,2);
    //1echo "<br>repeat =".$repeat;
    if($repeat >0)
    {
        $mainword = substr($str,0,$repeat); 
        return $mainword;
    }
    else
    {
        return $str;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I have used confidence as a way around this issue, i know it is too late but hope it helps.

```
 for (let i = event.resultIndex; i < event.results.length; i++) {
            if (!(event.results[i][0].confidence > 0)) continue;
            if (event.results[i].isFinal && event.results[i][0].confidence >= 0.7) {
              finalTranscript = event.results[i][0].transcript;
            } else {
              this.feedback += event.results[i][0].transcript;
            }
 }
```